# Days tracker in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula, excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet with these 3 columns

(1) starting date (can have a value or be blank, except it cannot be blank when closure has a value)
(2) closing date (can have a value or be blank)
(3) days passed (actual days, weekends and such included)

I would like to know which formula i can use to have this result:

If (2) is blank, then (3) has to show the date difference between today and (1), obviously updating every day

If (2) has a valid value,then (3) should be the date differenze betweeen (2) and (1)

If both (1) and (2) are blank, then it should show a string value like "waiting"

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Look into IF() and TODAY().

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Formula in column 3 is:

```
 =IF(AND(A2="";B2="");"waiting";IF(B2="";TODAY()-A2;B2-A2))
```